# Virtualenv not functioning/set-up correctly. 'Access denied' when trying to call python.exe outside Scripts directory

Tags: python, virtualenv

After activating my virtualenv, I'm getting an 'access denied' error when trying to run the python.exe file outside of the virtualenv/Scripts directory. 
I've been using this virtualenv for weeks without this problem, and I'm not sure what happened to cause this error. A little more information about the virtualenv & my device:

- It's on a network drive
- It's on a work network that uses a proxy
- It's running on Windows 10

I've already tried restarting my device, running an administrative prompt, checking the activate.bat file, checking the python.exe file size (as suggested in other threads), and checking for instances of python running in the background. Also, (obviously) I've tried deactivating and reactivating the virtualenv.

Suggestions?[image: cmd capture]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is I am experiencing access issues to the Network Drive that my virtual environment is on. Since this local clone of the repository is on the C-drive, when I navigate to the Scripts directory (on the C drive) it runs the python script that is there. However, the activate.bat file is really mapping the virtualenv to the network drive. So, whenever I try to run a file (like python.exe) on that drive, I get an access denied error.

I simply need to contact my network administrator to have this issue resolved.